# What's the easiest way to retrieve the contents of a webpage via PHP?

Tags: php

I want to write a function to retrieve the contents of a webpage so it works like:

```
$url = "example.com";
$pageContent = RetrievePageContent($url);
```

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959063/how-to-send-a-get-request-from-php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$pageContent = file_get_contents($url);
```

From: [`file_get_contents`](http://us.php.net/file_get_contents)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents), which does exactly what you want:

```
$url = "http://example.com";
$pageContent = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: You must specify the http:// in the URL for PHP to know which method by which to access the resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [fopen command](http://php.net/fopen) and pass it a URL.  However, this ability might be disabled by your host.  The best practice would be to use the [cURL functions](http://php.net/curl).  The [documentation includes sample code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) that does exactly what you're trying to do.