# Requesting JSON from PHP

Tags: php, http, file-get-contents

I am trying to retrieve data from a server which usually returns it in `XML`, however I trying to request it in a JSON format (if requested correctly it will return the data in `JSON`).

```
$header = array(
           'http' => array(
             'header'=>"Content-type: application/json"
           ),
        );

$response = file_get_contents($query, false, $header);
print_r($response);
```

This approach was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959063/how-to-send-a-get-request-from-php). Currently the program does not return anything.
Does anyone spot any potential problems with this?

Comment: Whoever manages the server or application you are requesting from should be able to tell you how to properly request JSON for that particular server or application.

Comment: @SajanParikh: The HTTP standard also tells you how.  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1

Comment: @SLaks of course, but the application or server you're requesting from has to honor that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the HTTP `Accept` header to tell the server that you want it to give you JSON:

```
Accept: application/json
```

(assuming that the remote server is correctly implemented to read the header)

---

The `Content-Type` *request* header indicates the type of the payload that you are POSTing.
In your case, it does not apply, since you're sending a GET request.