# How do I call an API in controller function

Tags: php, laravel, get

I have a function in controller and I want to call an HTTP request passing url like GET request in AJAX but I couldn't figure how do I use it using php I tried this

```
public function sendAPIRequest()
{
    $url = "https://myapi.com?apikey=".$api."&message=".$message."&receiver=".$receiver;
    //This is what I tried
    file_get_contents($url);
    //But it didn't work
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a GET request from PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959063/how-to-send-a-get-request-from-php)

Comment: @ThomasSnijder yess it is possible bro! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Guzzle Package](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) for Laravel , [Guzzle PHP](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/)

```
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', "https://myapi.com?apikey=".$api."&message=".$message."&receiver=".$receiver);
echo $res->getStatusCode();
// 200
echo $res->getHeaderLine('content-type');
// 'application/json; charset=utf8'
echo $res->getBody();
// '{"id": 1420053, "name": "guzzle", ...}'
```

Comment: Do I have to like require anything? like composer require gizzle