# webhook error when trying to do ajax

Tags: php, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I modified it all now I have this file that makes my api work.

auth.php:

```
<?php
include 'Unirest.php';



function login()
{

    $headers = array('Accept' => 'application/json');
    $data = array(
        "grant_type" => "password",
        "client_id" => "myclientid",
        "client_secret" => "myclientsecret",
        "username" => "username",
        "password" => "password"
    );

    $response = Unirest\Request::post('http://i-scent.fr/api/oauth_token', $headers, $data);
    //    $response->code;
    //    $response->headers;
    return $response->body->access_token;
}

function device_info($device_id,$token){

    $header = array('Accept' => 'application/json', 
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token );
    $response = Unirest\Request::get('http://i-scent.fr/api/devices/'.$device_id,$header);
    echo $response->body->name;
    echo "</br>";

}

function diffuse($device_id,$token,$duration,$intensity){

    $header = array('Accept' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token );
    $data = array('time' => 1, 'percent' => 50);

    $body = Unirest\Request\Body::form($data);


    $response = Unirest\Request::put('http://i-scent.fr/app_dev.php/api/device/'.$device_id.'/actions/diffusion',$header,$body);
    echo $response->code;
    echo "</br>";


}
```

When I use all the functions in a simple script it works perfectly on my website. But when I put it like this in my webhook, I have error 500 internal server error. I have all the unirest libraries.

```
<?php
include "auth.php";

function processMessage($update) {
    if($update["result"]["action"] == "sayHello"){

        $token = login();
        $name = device_info("1966",$token);
        diffuse("1966",$token,"0.5","50");

        sendMessage(array(
            "source" => $update["result"]["source"],
            "speech" => "bonjour webhook",
            "displayText" => "bonjour webhook",
            "contextOut" => array()
        ));

    }
}

function sendMessage($parameters) {
    echo json_encode($parameters);
}


$update_response = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($update_response, true);
if (isset($update["result"]["action"])) {

    processMessage($update);
}
```

Error 500 is supposed to mean that the webhokk's script crashed somewhere but I don't know where and why.

Comment: Please clarify two things: (1) What do you mean by "this way doesn't fix my problem." What, exactly, is the problem? I've lost track at this point. (2) "my script at ... doesn't run". Do you mean the PHP script? Or did it output a <script> tag which you are expecting to run?

Comment: I tried to make it clearer.

Comment: I'm going to assume that first file is "auth.php", correct?

Comment: yes I forgot to put the name sorry

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2**

Based on your most recent code, you're including "auth.php", which works in the original environment (which is being called as part of a web page, it sounds like).

Your code has two functions, `device_info()` and `diffuse()`, which output their results instead of returning them. This output isn't JSON, and includes HTML markup. This is being sent as part of the result of your webhook and will cause what is returned to be invalid.

**Update**

Based on your latest code, there are still many logical, and a few syntactical, problems.

A "500 Internal Server Error" indicates that your program didn't run correctly and crashed for some reason. As posted, it is missing a closing }, which could be the problem if that isn't in your actual code.

Even if you fix that, there are many issues with the code:

- It isn't clear what you intend to do with the results of calling your "test1" script. You store them in `$data` and don't do anything with it.
- You're calling the other website (test1) before you look at what the user has asked you to do. Which is fine, but then why do you care what the user is asking you?

**Original Answer**

There are a few errors here, but the underlying problem is that you're mixing up where things run and the capabilities of the caller to your webhook.

For a Dialogflow webhook, Google/Dialogflow is sending JSON (which you seem to be handling ok), and expecting back JSON. Although it looks like you send this back as part of `send_message()`, you're also sending something back when you call `connexion()`. What you're sending back in this case is **not** JSON, but HTML with JavaScript.

Which leads to the second problem - If this was php that was generating an HTML page that included a script, you'd be in fine shape. But it isn't. You have to send back **only** JSON.

You can do something like this to call the other API and get back the contents:

```
$body = file_get_contents("http://google-home.exhalia.fr/test1");
```

Which will set `$body` to the body of the page you've called. What you do with that, at that point, is up to you. But you need to make this call *before* your call to `send_message()` because you want to represent the contents as part of what you're saying.

(See [How to send a GET request from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959063/how-to-send-a-get-request-from-php) for a discussion of other methods available to you in case you need to do a POST, use header information, etc.)

Comment: I've updated my answer, but I don't know what you mean by "I don't want to get the content of index.php except if I can run it like that."

Comment: I changed it to `$body = file_get_contents("http://google-home.exhalia.fr/test1/index.php");` as you said. I deleted the function connexion and I've put this at the very beginning of my code. In test1 folder there is index.php that just runs different api to log, get informations on devices and send orders. What I want is just to call this script that already works well. It doesn't display or return anything.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you're running that script. This doesn't seem like a very useful experience, however, if it takes no input and returns no output.

Comment: Still not working with this code I just edited in the post. I don't understand why.

Comment: Updated answer again (put it on top)

Comment: I deleted every outputs but it didn't change anything. The problem is still here.

Comment: Nevermind, problem was on the server. Curl was missing it works now. Thanks for help.