# Passing variable in a URL(php)

Tags: php

Is there a way that I can possibly pass my variable from an offline page to my online page?

I have the following code on a page on Website A that contains the email of my receiver:
`$emailOutput = $dataQuery_email->contact_email;`

This is my code so far but it's not working.
`file_get_contents("http://my_domain.com/sendEmail.php?email_id=".$emailOutput);`

On my sendEmail.php I did this:

`$to = $_GET[$emailOutput];`

Is there any other way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a GET request from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959063/how-to-send-a-get-request-from-php)

Answer (score 0):

Change `$to = $_GET[$emailOutput];` to `$to = $_GET['email_id'];` as that is the name of the get parameter you have passed in your URL.

Take a look at [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) for a basic overview of HTTP GET

Answer (score 0):

Your url parameter was email_id, and $emailOutput was a variable/ value that youve passed to the url, 
replace $_GET[$emailOutput] with $_GET["email_id"];